# Why is my Nexus 5548UP not adding ARP entries for the trunk to a 2960S?

Tags: cisco, arp, cisco-catalyst, cisco-nexus

I have a Nexus 5548UP trunked to a Catalyst 2960S.  I have verified that spanning tree is working.  I explicitly made the 2960S the root bridge for all VLANs as a temporary measure since it is trunked to an ASA for inter-VLAN routing (router on-a-stick).

If I run `debug ip arp event` I get messages like the following:

```
2011 Dec 17 00:59:19.770605 arp: arp_process_receive_packet_msg: Destination address is not local 192.168.99.1 on Vlan99
```

These are definitely coming across the trunk, but I would have figured that the ARP table would list the trunk port as the port for that entry.  What does `Destination address is not local` mean?

Why is my Nexus 5548UP not adding ARP entries for the trunk to a 2960S even though ARP frames are pas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an unused IP Address on the SVI and the Nexus will begin to build an ARP table for it.

For example:

```
conf
int vlan 99
   ip address 192.168.99.2/24
```

From here on out you can ping devices on VLAN 99 that are on the 2960S :)